# DispForm, Target Audience or hide contents based on security group

Tags: sharepoint-online, audience-targeting

Is there a way to hide certain column from DispForm based on if the current user is part of a Security Group?  Unfortunately, the security group contains **Active Directory** group not individual names thats why I was hoping `target audience` would work.

Here's what I've done so far:

In DispForm.aspx, added a content editor web part linked to a txt file with

```
<div id="hidValue"></div>
```

Added a `target audience` in the CEWP.

In SharePoint Designer, I edited the custom `DispForm.aspx` and added the following

```
<xsl:variable name="varInfo" select="@AdditionalInfo"/>
<script language="javascript">
    var i =<xsl:value-of select="$varInfo"/>;
    alert('<xsl:value-of select="$varInfo"/>');
</script>
```

The alert works but when I attempted to populate the `<div id="hidValue"></div>` with any of below lines, none of them worked:

```
document.getElementById("hidValue").innerHTML = '<xsl:value-of select="$varInfo"/>';
document.getElementById("hidValue").innerHTML = {$varInfo};
```

Basically, I want the value of `@AdditionalInfo` hidden to all except for the target audience.

I also tried below code which identifies the current user's group but does not work if user is part of an AD group inside the SharePoint group:

```
var ckUserGrp = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +'/_api/web/currentuser/groups'
$.getJSON(ckUserGrp, function (data) {
$.each(data.value, function (key, value) {
    var grpName = value.Title;
    console.log(grpName);
});
})
```

Comment: For How many groups you want to show this field?

Comment: At the moment, the demand is just for one SharePoint group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by switching the Content Editor to `Script Editor` web part with the following code in custom DispForm:

```
<div class="hidInfo" id="varInfo"><xsl:value-of select="@AdditionalInfo" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></div>

<script language="javascript">
     var i = document.getElementById("varInfo").innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("hidValue").innerHTML = i;
</script>
```

Then added a css to hide the additional info

```
.hidInfo {
    display: none;
}
```

Seems to work so far with limited testing.